# Busybox init, is it possible to delay execution of init.d script conditionally?

Tags: pigpio, init.d, init

I would like to boot into a python app. My python app has the excellent pigpiod daemon as a prerequisite. I am using Busybox init process. I have a pigpiod launch script /etc/init.d/SXpigpiod and my python application launch script /etc/init.d/SYmyapp (X is smaller than Y).

The problem I encounter is this - pigpiod immediately forks thus init moves on swiftly, however it takes some time before pigpiod is *actually* responsive. If myapp is called by init too soon, it's game over because python pigpio module cannot connect to pigpiod. I know it is a simple race condition because if I run /etc/init.d/SYmyapp from console everything is fine. Also, making X as small as possible and Y as large as possible, thus ensuring that several other init tasks are executed in between (notably S40network), resolves the problem. This is not good enough though, I need to minimise cold boot time and most of the other init tasks will disappear eventually.
I have tried looping inside myapp init script waiting for pigpiod to start responding, like this:

```
while [ "$(pigs pigpv 2>&1 >/dev/null)" = 'socket connect failed' ]
do
  #echo "pigpiod down"
  sleep 0.1
done
```

This appears to block pigpiod from ever loading. Implementing a similar thing inside python app also appears to block pigpiod from loading:

```
while not pigpio.pi().connected:
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Is there a way to ensure that myapp is started as soon as pigpiod is responding, without blocking pigpiod initilaisation?

Comment: You really shouldn't use deprecated SysV init scripts anymore on new projects. it's no wonder that run into trouble.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of problem that systemd was designed to solve. If you don't want to use it, just throw in a long enough delay (`sleep 10`) and be done with it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble to look at this. I have a reason for using Busybox init (not even sysvinit). Currently systemd requires glibc in Buildroot which I would like to avoid. Busybox init (default in Buildroot) allows me to use musl instead resulting in more compact code which should translate into shorter cold boot time. I think the problem is with pigpiod forking too early - before it is fully functional. I am not sure systemd would deal with this any better.

Comment: I have not found a way to resolve this with `pigpio`, but I have now sidestepped the problem by replacing `pigpio` functions that I needed (rotary encoder and hardware pwm) with native linux drivers via `dtoverlay=rotary-encoder,..` & `dtoverlay=pwm-2chan,...` statements in config.txt. Cold boot time is now 10s, half of what it was with systemd and `pigpiod`.